# Correct way to fetch posts which are posted 3 days ago?

Tags: php, mysql

My data has a column named "date" which includes post dates in unix date format. I am using this query to fetch posts which are posted 3 days ago

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM track WHERE  
FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND
FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY");
```

This works, however, it selects posts by date which are in range of -48 hours and -72 hours.
But I want to fetch posts by day names. I mean, for example if a post added 40 hours ago, now its not theorically 48 hours (2 days) but if we look at the day name, it was 2 days ago. How can I fetch posts like that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM track WHERE  
FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

Comment: CUR_DATE() should be CURDATE()

Comment: Ooops. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: So that todays should be "FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()"
Its weird that I get the same results with my before queries.

Comment: Ok I have solved the issue by setting *my timezone in mySQL by doing
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+3:00'");